# Use session in external js file

Tags: ajax, codeigniter, session

I want to use session in an external js file, but it's not working. I know that it's not possible to access a session in an external AJAX file, but does anyone have solution for it?

When I insert code in my view it runs correctly, moreover I think the URL is incorrect too! I use CodeIgniter for the back-end.

```js
function show_msg() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'ajax',
        url: '<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/chat/showmsg',
        async: false,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            var user = '<?php echo $this->session->userdata('username'); ?>';
            var html = '';
            var i;
            for (i = 14; i >= 0; i--) {
                if (data[i].user !== user) {
                    html +=
                            '<span style="color:green;font-size:12px;">' + data[i].user + '</span>' + ' ' + '<span style="color:dimgrey;font-size:10px;">' + data[i].date + '</span>' + '<div style="margin-right:25px;margin-bottom:25px;border:0px solid grey; border-radius: 0px 12px 12px 12px; padding:10px;width:auto;background-color:white;;box-shadow:0px 0px 0px 0px grey;direction:rtl;">' + data[i].msg + '</div>';
                } else {
                    html +=
                            '<span style="color:green;font-size:12px;">' + "" + '</span>' + ' ' + '<span style="color:dimgrey;font-size:10px;">' + data[i].date + '</span>' + '<div style="margin-left:30px;margin-bottom:25px;border:0px solid grey; border-radius: 8px 0px 8px 8px; padding:10px;width:auto;background-color:#bbf490;box-shadow:0px 0px 0px grey;direction:rtl;">' + data[i].msg + '</div>';
                }
            }
            $('#show_data').html(html);
        }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way of inserting PHP variables in the external .js files. Because PHP does not parse js files. A quick and dirty way is to declare a JS variable(declare the variable carefully because of global variable pollution, use descriptive name) in the php view file like this.

```
     <script type="text/javascript">
        var session_user_id = '<?php echo $this->session->userdata('username'); ?>';
        var base_url = '<?php echo base_url(); ?>';
    </script>
```

and use this variable in your external js file

```
        function show_msg() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'ajax',
            url: base_url + 'index.php/chat/showmsg',
            async: false,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                var user = session_user_id;
                var html = '';
                var i;
                for (i = 14; i >= 0; i--) {
                    if (data[i].user !== user) {
                        html +=
                                '<span style="color:green;font-size:12px;">' + data[i].user + '</span>' + ' ' + '<span style="color:dimgrey;font-size:10px;">' + data[i].date + '</span>' + '<div style="margin-right:25px;margin-bottom:25px;border:0px solid grey; border-radius: 0px 12px 12px 12px; padding:10px;width:auto;background-color:white;;box-shadow:0px 0px 0px 0px grey;direction:rtl;">' + data[i].msg + '</div>';
                    } else {
                        html +=
                                '<span style="color:green;font-size:12px;">' + "" + '</span>' + ' ' + '<span style="color:dimgrey;font-size:10px;">' + data[i].date + '</span>' + '<div style="margin-left:30px;margin-bottom:25px;border:0px solid grey; border-radius: 8px 0px 8px 8px; padding:10px;width:auto;background-color:#bbf490;box-shadow:0px 0px 0px grey;direction:rtl;">' + data[i].msg + '</div>';
                    }
                }
                $('#show_data').html(html);
            }
        });
    }
```